# I can't build Android project in Dreamweaver

Tags: android, cordova, dreamweaver

I can't build Android project in Dreamweaver. When I go to Site -> Mobile Applications -> Build  and I click on Android, I see this window appears:-
[image]

And it's the log file that the program said:
[Download](http://www.4shared.com/file/tLIZ58R1/buildlog.html?)
This is the log file if can't download it:

> WARNING: no icon was specified in app settings. using default.
>   WARNING: no splash screen was specified in app settings. using
>   default. Cloning seed app for Android 
>   ____________________ set ANT_HOME=C:\PROGRA~2\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\APACHE~1 set
>   ANDROID_HOME=C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1 set
>   JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~2\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\JDK set
>   PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH% cd C:\Users\Sina\Desktop\COMCOM~1.UNN
>   C:\windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /u /c
>   C:\PROGRA~2\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\DWPHON~1\android\scripts\droidGap.bat
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver
>   CS5.5\Configuration\NativeAppFramework\DWPhoneGap\android\PhoneGapApp"
>   "Unnamed Site 2" com.company.unnamed_site_2 1.0 "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Android\android-sdk" 2
>   ____________________
>
> C Created project directory:
>   C:\Users\Sina\Desktop\com.company.unnamed_site_2_Android\com.company.unnamed_site_2
>
> Created directory
>   C:\Users\Sina\Desktop\com.company.unnamed_site_2_Android\com.company.unnamed_site_2\src\com\company\unnamed_site_2
>
> Added file
>   C:\Users\Sina\Desktop\com.company.unnamed_site_2_Android\com.company.unnamed_site_2\src\com\company\unnamed_site_2\DefaultActivity.java
>
> Created directory
>   C:\Users\Sina\Desktop\com.company.unnamed_site_2_Android\com.company.unnamed_site_2\res
>
> Created directory
>   C:\Users\Sina\Desktop\com.company.unnamed_site_2_Android\com.company.unnamed_site_2\bin
>
> Created directory
>   C:\Users\Sina\Desktop\com.company.unnamed_site_2_Android\com.company.unnamed_site_2\libs
>
> Created directory
>   C:\Users\Sina\Desktop\com.company.unnamed_site_2_Android\com.company.unnamed_site_2\res\values
>
> Added file
>   C:\Users\Sina\Desktop\com.company.unnamed_site_2_Android\com.company.unnamed_site_2\res\values\strings.xml
>
> Created directory
>   C:\Users\Sina\Desktop\com.company.unnamed_site_2_Android\com.company.unnamed_site_2\res\layout
>
> Added file
>   C:\Users\Sina\Desktop\com.company.unnamed_site_2_Android\com.company.unnamed_site_2\res\layout\main.xml
>
> Added file
>   C:\Users\Sina\Desktop\com.company.unnamed_site_2_Android\com.company.unnamed_site_2\AndroidManifest.xml
>
> Added file
>   C:\Users\Sina\Desktop\com.company.unnamed_site_2_Android\com.company.unnamed_site_2\build.xml
>
> Added file
>   C:\Users\Sina\Desktop\com.company.unnamed_site_2_Android\com.company.unnamed_site_2\proguard-project.txt
>
> CLONE SUCCESSFUL
>
> ____________________ set ANT_HOME=C:\PROGRA~2\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\APACHE~1 set
>   ANDROID_HOME=C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1 set
>   JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~2\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\JDK set
>   PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH% cd C:\Users\Sina\Desktop\COMCOM~1.UNN
>   C:\windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /u /c
>   C:\PROGRA~2\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\APACHE~1\bin\ant.bat
>   debug
>   ____________________  Buildfile: C:\Users\Sina\Desktop\COMCOM~1.UNN\build.xml
>
> -set-mode-check:
>
> -set-debug-files:
>
> -check-env:
>
> [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 20.0.1
>
> [checkenv] Installed at C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
>
> -setup:
>
> ```
>  [echo] Project Name: unnamed_site_2
> ```
>
> [gettype] Project Type: Application
>
> -set-debug-mode:
>
> -debug-obfuscation-check:
>
> -build-setup:
>
> ```
>  [echo] Resolving Build Target for unnamed_site_2...
> ```
>
> [gettarget] Project Target:   Google APIs
>
> [gettarget] Vendor:           Google Inc.
>
> [gettarget] Platform Version: 2.1
>
> [gettarget] API level:        7
>
> ```
>  [echo] ----------
>
>  [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
>
> [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\Sina\Desktop\COMCOM~1.UNN\bin\res
>
> [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\Sina\Desktop\COMCOM~1.UNN\gen
>
> [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\Sina\Desktop\COMCOM~1.UNN\bin\classes
>
>  [echo] ----------
>
>  [echo] Resolving Dependencies for unnamed_site_2...
> ```
>
> [dependency] Library dependencies:
>
> [dependency] No Libraries
>
> [dependency]
>
> [dependency] ------------------
>
> [dependency] API<=15: Adding annotations.jar to the classpath.
>
> ```
>  [echo] ----------
>
>  [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...
> ```
>
> [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on
>
> -pre-build:
>
> -code-gen:
>
> [mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
>
> [mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
>
> ```
>  [echo] Handling aidl files...
>
>  [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
>
>  [echo] ----------
>
>  [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
> ```
>
> [renderscript] No RenderScript files to compile.
>
> ```
>  [echo] ----------
>
>  [echo] Handling Resources...
>
>  [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
>
>  [echo] ----------
>
>  [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
> ```
>
> [buildconfig] Generating BuildConfig class.
>
> -pre-compile:
>
> -compile:
>
> ```
> [javac] Compiling 3 source files to C:\Users\Sina\Desktop\COMCOM~1.UNN\bin\classes
> ```
>
> -post-compile:
>
> -obfuscate:
>
> -dex:
>
> ```
>   [dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into C:\Users\Sina\Desktop\COMCOM~1.UNN\bin\classes.dex...
>
>    [dx] Could not create the Java virtual machine.
>
>    [dx] Error occurred during initialization of VM
>
>    [dx] Could not reserve enough space for object heap
> ```
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:850:
>   The following error occurred while executing this line:
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:852:
>   The following error occurred while executing this line:
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:864:
>   The following error occurred while executing this line:
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:266:
>   null returned: 1
>
> Total time: 8 seconds
>
> WARNING: no icon was specified in app settings. using default.
>   WARNING: no splash screen was specified in app settings. using
>   default.
>
> ____________________ set ANT_HOME=C:\PROGRA~2\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\APACHE~1 set
>   ANDROID_HOME=C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1 set
>   JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~2\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\JDK set
>   PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH% cd C:\Users\Sina\Desktop\COMCOM~1.UNN
>   C:\windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /u /c
>   C:\PROGRA~2\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\APACHE~1\bin\ant.bat
>   debug
>   ____________________  Buildfile: C:\Users\Sina\Desktop\COMCOM~1.UNN\build.xml
>
> -set-mode-check:
>
> -set-debug-files:
>
> -check-env:
>
> [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 20.0.1
>
> [checkenv] Installed at C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
>
> -setup:
>
> ```
>  [echo] Project Name: unnamed_site_2
> ```
>
> [gettype] Project Type: Application
>
> -set-debug-mode:
>
> -debug-obfuscation-check:
>
> -build-setup:
>
> ```
>  [echo] Resolving Build Target for unnamed_site_2...
> ```
>
> [gettarget] Project Target:   Google APIs
>
> [gettarget] Vendor:           Google Inc.
>
> [gettarget] Platform Version: 2.1
>
> [gettarget] API level:        7
>
> ```
>  [echo] ----------
>
>  [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
>
>  [echo] ----------
>
>  [echo] Resolving Dependencies for unnamed_site_2...
> ```
>
> [dependency] Library dependencies:
>
> [dependency] No Libraries
>
> [dependency]
>
> [dependency] ------------------
>
> [dependency] API<=15: Adding annotations.jar to the classpath.
>
> ```
>  [echo] ----------
>
>  [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...
> ```
>
> [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on
>
> -pre-build:
>
> -code-gen:
>
> [mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
>
> [mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
>
> [mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
>
> ```
>  [echo] Handling aidl files...
>
>  [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
>
>  [echo] ----------
>
>  [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
> ```
>
> [renderscript] No RenderScript files to compile.
>
> ```
>  [echo] ----------
>
>  [echo] Handling Resources...
>
>  [aapt] Found Deleted Target File
>
>  [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
>
>  [echo] ----------
>
>  [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
> ```
>
> [buildconfig] Generating BuildConfig class.
>
> -pre-compile:
>
> -compile:
>
> ```
> [javac] Compiling 2 source files to C:\Users\Sina\Desktop\COMCOM~1.UNN\bin\classes
> ```
>
> -post-compile:
>
> -obfuscate:
>
> -dex:
>
> ```
>   [dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into C:\Users\Sina\Desktop\COMCOM~1.UNN\bin\classes.dex...
>
>    [dx] Could not create the Java virtual machine.
>
>    [dx] Error occurred during initialization of VM
>
>    [dx] Could not reserve enough space for object heap
> ```
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:850:
>   The following error occurred while executing this line:
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:852:
>   The following error occurred while executing this line:
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:864:
>   The following error occurred while executing this line:
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:266:
>   null returned: 1
>
> Total time: 4 seconds

What should I do?

Comment: Read through the log, extract the important parts and add the to your question.

Comment: We don't register somewhere to see your logs...